# Firefox Quantum (63) WebVR Oculus Headset Tracking but No Video Over Oculus Home

Tags: webvr, oculus

I'm trying to play video webvr content in firefox quantum version 63.0.3 from an NVidia GTX 1080 graphics card on the latest drivers. I have audio and tracking with the oculus headset, but no video. What can I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here with HTC Vive on Firefox 63.03 with Nvidia GTX1080.

VRdisplay is recognized by browser and i can request pose sensor data. But there is just no Video on the headset. vrDisplay.submitFrame() gets called.

the only difference i noticed in SteamVR between Firefox Nightly (65), Chrome (70.0.3538.102) **which are both working** and firefox quantum is that steamVR also claims that **(unresponsive) Firefox** while rpesenting. The other browsers only show **(unresponsive) XX** while NOT presenting.

for my setup: I am rendering a stack of multiple scenes. on two different canvases (one mono for mirror mode display, one stereoscopic.). This works fine in Chrome and Firefox Nightly...

**edit:** funny thing. standard aframe and threejs examples seem to work

**edit2:** funny thing #2. Firefox 63 seems to **require the canvas to be added to the dom**, nightly 65 doesnt.